# how to prevent jquery animation horizontal position jump when animating a fixed position centered div in firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, jquery-animate, css-position

I have a page with a box that pops out from the bottom when its header bar is clicked using jquery animate.

The pop-out box is set as position fixed and it is centered.  In chrome, when the header is clicked the box slides out as expected, but in firefox it jumps to the right when it animates.

There seems to be some sort of bug with jquery in firefox which is determining the width of the page including the socrollbar. that is causing a position shift when there is a scrollbar, but I can't figure a way around it while keeping the functionality of the popout.

Both Firefox and Chrome are updated to the latest versions.

[here is a tinker.io link that demonstrates the issue](http://tinker.io/e8bb6/6)

I also include the code from the demonstration:

```css
#holder{
position:relative;
width:300px;
height:1400px;
margin:0 auto;
border:1px solid black;
}


#bar{
position:fixed;
width:300px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
background-color:#C0C0C0;
bottom:-170px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-150px;
}

#header{
width:100%;
height:30px;
background-color:#600000;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder"></div>

<div id="bar">
<div id="header"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var open = false;

    $("#header").click(function(){
    if (open == false){
    $("#bar").animate({
        "bottom" : "0px"
    });

    open = true;
    }else{
    $("#bar").animate({
        "bottom" : "-170px"
    });

    open = false;
    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is not relative to your problem but you have a typo here: postion:relative;  {position}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to modify the HTML as I've updated the tinker at http://tinker.io/e8bb6/9

```
<div id="holder">
    <div id="bar">
        <div id="header"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```